# How to reflow container after a transform has been applied to child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to display `div` boxes in a container and arrange them horizontally. As this can get quite wide I also want to provide a zoom slider which will rescale these `div`s.

This works but the items are rescaled but not repositioned. I have created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtphLyem/5/.

I would like the container to re-layout the items after the transform has been applied. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes with `transform`, because transform only "simulates" bigger elements, but doesn't change any **width** values or sth. like that which means your browser still tries to layout with your raw values.

You could achieve such an effect by just changing the font-size, which changes width, height and position all by itself.

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mtphLyem/7/

```
function zoom(zoomFactor) {
    $('.container > .step').css('font-size', zoomFactor + 'px');
}
```

**Update**
From comment below:

'Then you might also change margins since changing size would again trigger the scaling. This one looks quite experimenting and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do that but still it seems to work: [jsfiddle.net/mtphLyem/10](http://jsfiddle.net/mtphLyem/10)'

Comment: Nice try! Would work in some situations but I have images (which I left out of the jsfiddle example). These also need to be transformed which is not so easily done - I think.

Comment: Oh fine, did not know this. Then you might also change `margins` since changing `size` would again trigger the scaling. This one looks quite experimenting and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do that but still it seems to work: jsfiddle.net/mtphLyem/10

Comment: Looks very good! Thanks. I'll edit your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, just bind to the change event:

```
$("#zoom").on("input change", function() { zoom($(this).val()) });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but you haven't understood the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Sorry for misreading your post, but your jsfiddle was not working in my browser so I just asumed that.
You might have to switch to modifying width and height. Since you know your width, your new zoom will always be `"width": 300*zoomFactor` if your zoom factor is a value between 1 and 10: `zoomFactor = 1+ (zoomfactor/10)` //of course you can always adjust this forumla. Hope this helps!